# 16-Bit textures in XNA 4 on WP7

Tags: xna-4.0, windows-phone-7

WP7 textures are supported in the Reach-Profile that WP7 devices falls into. But XNA converts all my ressources upon adding them to a project to RGBA8, that's insane, the displays of WP7 devices are 16 Bit!

**Information:** WP7 SDK 7.1 (XNA 4), Visual Studio 2010

**Question part 1:** How can I add a RGB565 texture to a XNA project and what is the correct way to load them inside a game?

**Question part 2:** Is there a reasonable 16 Bit texture format (within Reach) that supports alpha with MORE than 1Bit?

**Question part 3:** Is the normal rendertarget (I think that's what the screenbuffer is?) already 16 bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1:** When adding a texture with the default **Texture - XNA Framework** content processor it gives you three choices in the **Texture format** property: Color, Compressed and No Change. You must set **No Change** and use a source texture that is already in a 16-bit format; for example a PNG image or a DDS image. Or, you can do your own content processor and force change of all your textures to 16-bit (although it is a bit overkill).

**Question 2:** The available 16-bit formats are 565 (no alpha), 5551 (1-bit alpha) and 4444 (4-bit alpha). Or, you can use DXT5 that has 32-bit alpha, although this will kill your soft gradients and give them a blocky appearance.

**Question 3:** Maybe, maybe not. It depends on the hardware and OS version. Some phones set 16-bit by default, but ALL of them support 32-bit. So, to make sure you have a 32-bit backbuffer, go to the constructor of your Game class and set this line:

```
graphics.PreferredBackBufferFormat = SurfaceFormat.Color;
```

Comment: Please also add how to load the textures (or where I have to define as which format the file is interpreted) for question 1 (the last line of the question), everything else is perfect

Comment: Whoops sorry, talk about obvious.

Answer (score 0):

RGBA8 textures on a 16-bit display device are not so insane.  The graphics device may very well be performing all of it's calculations at a higher precision internally, then dithering down to 16-bit for the final display (this is not an outlandish concept - 3DFX did it in 1996).  RGBA8 can also be faster to operate on, to sample from, etc, as it's just a matter of accessing one byte from a byte[4] array; with 16-bit - because the size of each colour component doesn't map to any native data type - the driver will need to so some (very slightly, but overhead can pile up) tricksy stuff with bit shifts and bit masks.

Comment: Primary problem in this case is that afaik XNA 4 only likes uncompressed RGBA8 (big,slow) or DXT compressed data (which loads fast but looks... ugly on non 3d textures) and uncompressed data on a mobile game that should be smaller than 50 MB is insane I have a size budget, but I get your point that 16 bit is processor-unfriendly, yet this answer ignores all questions :-D

Comment: mh01: The memory wasting is a problem far worse than the little overhead that the bit masking operations produces. And depending on the hardware, there's no way to know if the full-screen dithering made by the GPU will be slower than sampling from 16-bit textures.
@NopeAndNever: no, XNA 4 supports other texture formats. Lemme explain in a longer answer.